# How can I subscribe (line by line) to the output of a blocking shell command in Clojure?

Tags: unix, clojure, core.async

Basically, I want to capture the first line of output (FIFO) of a shell command in some sort of object, whether an atom or a `chan`. I've looked at core.cache and core.async, but I've yet to find anything that can overcome the problem that `sh` (from `clojure.java.shell`) only returns a value when the command has stopped writing to standard output. How can I access the data it's emitting as it comes out? For example, I'd like to have an object that has the most recent line of output of `bspc subscribe`, `pactl subscribe`, or something of the like.

For context, I have written a configuration for lemonbar, a status bar which reads from standard input and writes to standard output. Currently, I have a bunch of `Thread`s that sleep for 100ms and update the output of things like `wmctrl -d`, `mpc current`, and such. I'd like instead to subscribe to these events as one could in Bash (`bspc subscribe | while read line ...`).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses `[com.kohlschutter.junixsocket/junixsocket-core "2.3.2"]` and `[me.raynes/fs "1.4.6"]`.

```
(ns so.unix-socket
    (:require
        [me.raynes.fs :as fs]
        [clojure.java.io :as io])
    (:import
        (org.newsclub.net.unix AFUNIXServerSocket AFUNIXSocketAddress)))


(def file-name (fs/temp-file "abc"))
(.deleteOnExit file-name)
(def file (io/file file-name))

(def server (doto (AFUNIXServerSocket/newInstance)
                (.. (bind (AFUNIXSocketAddress. file)))
                (.. (setSoTimeout 10000))))

(future
    (let [socket (.. server (accept))
          rdr    (io/reader (.getInputStream socket))]
        (loop [line (.readLine rdr)]
            (when (some? line)
                (println line)
                (recur (.readLine rdr))))))

(clojure.java.shell/sh "bash" "-c"
    (format "pactl subscribe|socat STDIN UNIX-CONNECT:%s"
            (.getAbsolutePath file-name)))
```